# Javascript alert wont dismiss (while loop)

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I'm trying to make a "How many fingers are you holding up" page, if i input 1-5 in the box, it works, but if i input more than 5, the alert wont disappear, can anyone help me with this? Sorry for the noob question
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

```js
document.getElementById("guess").onclick = function() {

  var gotIt = false;
  var guesess = 1;
  var x;

  while (gotIt == false) {
    x = Math.random();
    x = 6 * x;
    x = Math.floor(x);

    if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value == x) {
      gotIt = true;
    } else {
      if (guesess == 20) {
        alert("i give up");
      } else {
        guesses++;
      }
    }
  }
  alert("I got it! It was a " + x + "It only took me " + guesess + "guesses");
}
```

```html
<p>How many fingers are you holding up?</p>
<input id="myNumber" />
<button id="guess">Guess!!</button>
```

Comment: because you never set `gotIt` to false! Learn about `break;`

Comment: Look at the console: `ReferenceError: guesses is not defined`. However, your logic flawed. There is no point in having this loop. The user can't change the text input while the loop is running. But as epascarello said, `x` is it max `5`. So anything above 5 will not work.

Comment: `guesess` vs `guesses`

Comment: you have a typo - guesses

Comment: I think I misunderstood the issue. And the typo might actually not be in your code, otherwise you would never see the alert.  @epascarello  is right (you should make an answer!)

Comment: You need to pull this functionality and values outside of the function.  In the click function simply check the value and increment the number tries.

Comment: @epascarello is right, you never set the gotIt value to exit from the loop, but Felix is right too, the while loop will never catch any value the user enters.

Comment: Thanks alot! You guys are incredible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue, fix your typo: you use a mix of `guesess` and `guesses` they must all be the same.

Second issue, once the code is 'giving up', it isn't setting the flag to break the loop. You can use `break` after the alert to break the loop:

```
alert("i give up");
break;
```

Third issue, you will want a check to ensure you don't display the "i got it" message if no match is found (i.e. `gotIt` is still false):

```
if (gotIt) 
    alert("I got it! It was a " + x + "It only took me " + guesess + "guesses");
```

(alternatively you can put this alert inside the same if block that sets `gotIt = true`)

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/twumjvvz/)

Answer (score 0):

it is good idea to convert the input you
you can try replacing your java script code so that you can control conversion problems, and place your

`alert("I got it! It was a " + x + " It only took me " + guesess + "guesses");`

inside the if(x == n), because the alert will be popped out when the random number matches the input keyed,
try this code:

```
document.getElementById("guess").onclick = function() {
  var gotIt = false;
  var guesess = 1;
  var x;
  var num=parseInt(document.getElementById('myNumber').value);

  while (gotIt == false) {
    x = Math.random();
    x = 6 * x;
    x = Math.floor(x);

    if (x == num) {
      gotIt = true;
        alert("I got it! It was a " + x + " It only took me " + guesess + "guesses");
    } else {
      if (guesess == 20) {
        alert("i give up");
          break;
      } else {
        guesess++;
      }
    }
  }

}
```